# responseCode 4 of Google In-App Billing Library 1.0

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, response, in-app-billing

I'm programming in-app billing function in my app for ads free version by using google in-app billing library 1.0. And I've gone through all stages of [here codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#0) until now. However, I alway meet this error and returned `responseCode` is 4 (= `ITEM_UNAVAILABLE`) at `onPurchasesUpdated()`.

[image]

I had already registered my product item at google play console and activated it about 3 hours ago. Isn't it enough time? Or... are there any steps that I missed? Please let me know what is wrong? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you comply with the list?

- Signing release apk with release keystore
- Uploading the previously signed apk to at least alpha or beta google play
- Starting purchase flow with the specific id that is already activated

If you want to make test(no pay) purchases you have to register your phone user and the user should be different from the one of the developer account.

Comment: I registered user account of test device as you said. And It worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: If after this you got error code 5, install the app on the device from play store

Comment: After uploading to the test track, install the app from the test track, then make a test purchase.  After the test purchase from the test track install, I was able to uninstall the test track version, and do purchase testing with normal dev builds directly from Android Studio.