# No debug message and response code provided for Android in-app subscription. What do I need to configure else?

Tags: kotlin, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I would like to make a in-app purchase of Google Play subscription. When it comes to the implementation, it tells that "the item you were attempting to purchase could not be found."  The response code is 0 and no debug message. Would you please tell me what other parameters  I have to add ?

Given the billing client  ready and subscription details successfully fetched

```
  val skuDetails = subscriptionList.filter {  it.sku == sku }.first()
            println("selected skuDetails   : $skuDetails ")

            val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                .setDeveloperId(licenseKey)
                .build()
            val result = billingClient.  launchBillingFlow(this , flowParams)
            println("billing result response   : $result ")
            println("billing result response   : ${result.debugMessage} ")
            println("billing result response   : ${result.responseCode}")
```

Comment: did you solve the issue? I'm actually facing the exact same problem

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it with this answer:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307461/responsecode-4-of-google-in-app-billing-library-1-0/47308388#47308388) the trick was to use a different user to buy something from the developer user!!!!!